# Codeigniter validation--how to limit numerical value?

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I simply need to add a validation class that limits a numerical entry from being greater than 24.

Is this possible with CI's default validation classes or will I have to write a custom validation class?

Comment: Just curious why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no maximum or minimum comparison function in the [Form Validation Rule Reference](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference), so you can just [write your own validation function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

It's pretty straightforward.  Something like this should work:

```
function maximumCheck($num)
{
    if ($num > 24)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(
                        'your_number_field',
                        'The %s field must be less than 24'
                    );
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}


$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'your_number_field', 'Your Number', 'callback_maximumCheck'
    );
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use validation rule "`greater_than[24]`"

like for Example

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('your_number_field', 'Your Number', 'numeric|required|greater_than[24]');
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can, just make your own validation function and add it as a callback to validation rule. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Hence, you will have

```
...
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mynumber', 'This field', 'callback_numcheck');
....
function numcheck($in) {
  if (intval($in) > 24) {
   $this->form_validation->set_message('numcheck', 'Larger than 24');
   return FALSE;
  } else {
   return TRUE;
  }
}
```